# What is the paramater equivilant to?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
function onTouch(part) 
local human = part.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid") 
    if (human == nil) then
        return 
    end
    human.Health = human.Health - 10
end 
script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouch)
```

I'm new to coding in lua, and it is my first time using functions. I want to know what the "part" is equal to so that I can find out how to set up the human variable

```
local human = part.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
```

without using the "part," like what can I plug in so that works without even setting up part, because I want to do something with it in a loop:

```
local burnaffect = false
--local a = 0
function onTouch(part) 
local human = part.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid") 
    if (human == nil and burnaffect == false) then
        return 
    end
    a = 0
    burnaffect = true
end 
script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouch)

while burnaffect == true do
    local part = --????
    local human = part.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
    human.Health = human.Health - 10
end
```

The code may seem confusing but I'm fairly new so I don't know what is best yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to do is have a player "set on fire" when they touch a certain brick. The code below does exactly this, and I'll explain it line by line afterwards.

```
function onTouch(part)
    local human = part.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if (human == nil) then
        return 
    end
    local fire = Instance.new("Fire", part)
    while (human.Health > 0) do
        human.Health = human.Health - 10
        wait(0.1)
    end
end 
script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouch)
```

So, I'll start going through this.

- `function onTouch(part)`

We need to define the function first and give it a name so that we can reference it in the `Touched` event later. The `part` parameter is the `Part` object that touched the `script.Parent` object and caused the `Touched` event to fire. So, ROBLOX will automatically call this function whenever something touches your `script.Parent` and automatically input the `Part` that touched it as that first parameter, `part`.

- `local human = part.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")`

This will get the `Parent` of the `Part` that touched the block (because if a player is touching the block, it isn't going to give us the `Character`, it's going to give us an `Arm` or a `Leg` in the `part` variable, because that's the actual `Part` that touched it, so we need to get that `part's` `Parent`. Then, once we have the `Parent`, we want to get the `Humanoid` object inside of the `Character`. Then, we put that `Humanoid` object inside of the `human` variable (if we could find one, otherwise we put `nil` into that `human` variable).

- `if (human == nil) then`

We want to check if `human` is nil (which would mean we couldn't find a `Humanoid` object in the line before this one, which means whatever touched this isn't a real `Character`, so we'll want to `return` (which means stop running the function immediately).

- `local fire = Instance.new("Fire", part)`

This line isn't necessary, I added it because I thought if you wanted to simulate burning, this would help. You can leave it out if you'd like. It will create a new `Instance` of type `Fire`, and places it inside of the `part`. That is to say, if a player's `Leg` touches this part, a `Fire` will be put inside of that leg, which will make it appear to ignite in flames.

- `while (human.Health > 0) do`

We want to keep looping until the player dies (has a `human.Health` value of 0 or less) so we tell the loop to keep going while `human.Health` is greater than 0.

- `human.Health = human.Health - 10`

We'll deincrement the `human.Health` value by 10, and then `wait(0.1)`, which will cause the script to wait for 1/10 of a second (you can change this to a different number, but it is important to keep it as if you remove it, the loop will run extremely fast and kill the player immediately. If you want this to happen, you can remove the wait, but if you wanted to kill the player immediately, you could just set `human.Health = 0` in the first place.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask! Hope this answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

I remember when I used to use Lua for Roblox. The part is the part in the game that gets touched. You need to reference it so you can find the humanoid object it belongs to or lack of so your code can tell if it is a humanoid that touched it or not. Let me know if you have any further questions.